# remove main site string from subdomain string using htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I have set up a subdomain that is in its own folder and acting as a separate site. Problem is when the url is entered into the search bar it is changed and displays both the parent url and the sub domain url. So for example the main site is called siteone.co.uk and the sub domain site is called sitetwo.co.uk

When I open sitetwo.co.uk the following is displayed in the search bar:

http://www.siteone.co.uk/sitetwo.co.uk/

I only want to display http://www.sitetwo.co.uk/

I am sure this has something to do with the htaccess file but I have no idea how to write the code for htaccess and any help I have found on google or stack overflow does not directly answer my problem.

I think but am not sure that I need a second htaccess file that will sit in the root of sitetwo.co.uk?

Any help really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule as **very first rule** in `/sitetwo.co.uk/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sitetwo\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://sitetwo.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, This is working great for the home page but when I click on a link I am getting a 404 code. So when I try and open for example http://www.sitetwo.co.uk/newpage.php I am returned a 404? Also my links are absolute within the site. Thank you very much for your help : )

Comment: I am on mobile at present. But are you sure you have this code in./sitetwo.co.uk/.htaccess only?

Comment: Yes. Nothing else in the .htaccess file for sitetwo. There is a lot of rules in the siteone .htaccess file though. Not sure if that will effect sitetwo or not?

Comment: Hi anubhava, I had a problem before with a .htaccess file and you gave me some code that fixed (on stack overflow). I used the same code and it worked fine so you fixed my problem again :  ) Thank you so much for your time and help. I have marked your answer as the solution because you fixed it for me.